# THREE.js Texture is not visible with SVGRenderer

Tags: three.js

We've tried the next code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.0001, 999);
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 3 );
scene.add( camera );

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );

var image = $('#tmp')[0]

var texture = new THREE.Texture(image);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
var img_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, map: texture });
var plane_geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);

var imageMesh = new THREE.Mesh(plane_geometry, img_material);
imageMesh.doubleSided = true;
scene.add(imageMesh);

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

$('#container').append( renderer.domElement );
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

but when we switched to:

```js
renderer = new THREE.SVGRenderer();
```

it stop rendering texture over image geometry. Can anybody say why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THREE.SVGRenderer doesn't support textures.

Comment: I still wonder if it is in theory possible. I do not know a lot about SVG, but it does support images, and on a browser these could even be `data:` URIs. I'm not sure if they can be morphed though.

Comment: One idea, that could be done manually or with a custom renderer: Use both a canvas/OGL and the SVG renderer. Use the SVG shapes to "cut" the raster image into images for each of the SVG shapes, then include those in another svg group with data: URLs.