# Can three.js SVGRenderer render OBJ files?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to render an OBJ file with three.js

If I do it with WebGLRenderer, everything works fine, but if I try to do that with SVGRenderer or CanvasRenderer I get nothing.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the object is built with meshes (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411471/three-js-texture-is-not-visible-with-svgrenderer) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411471/three-js-texture-is-not-visible-with-svgrenderer))

Is that the case? Is there a workaround?

Code snippet follows for reference:

```
var j = 0;
if (j === 0) {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( r_width, r_height );
    console.log(renderer.domElement );
} else if (j === 1) {
    console.log('here');
    renderer = new THREE.SVGRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( r_width, r_height );
    console.log(renderer.domElement );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
    renderer.setQuality( 'low' );
    console.log(renderer.domElement );
} else if (j === 2){
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( r_width, r_height );
}
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

I obviously use j to switch renderer. If j is 1 or 2 nothing is rendered.

Comment: I have not used the SVGRenderer, but the source of the example [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#svg_sandbox) seems to suggest it supports meshes the same as the other renderers. The fact that the CanvasRenderer also does not work suggests to me that it is the way you are trying to dynamically change the renderer is your problem. Try using a canvas or svg renderer when the page first loads and see how you go.

Comment: So, it turns out that the scene takes about 10 seconds to render - that's why it looked like it didn't work. Now I know this and wait more patiently. It still completely freezes the browser. I've started by adding a setTimeout()